# How do I enable password protect for a page in asp.net - IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, apache, iis, logging

I think my question may be a duplicate, but I do not know what to search for.
I was use a functional name "password protect folder" in CPanel (php-apache linux) that when you enter a specific folder or file, you will see a prompt asking for username and password, if your account is in correct you will get a 401 status code returned.
Now I want this function in my asp.net mvc app, but I am not sure where to start. Does this functionality exist in MVC and IIS?

Comment: Did you mean Forms Authentication? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398049(v=vs.98).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would include an authentication & authorization sections in your web.config file.

[ASP.NET Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291347%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you're working with ASP.Net MVC, I think reading [Chapter 7 of the Music Store Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-7) might be of some use for you. [Jon Galloway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5/jon-galloway) goes into a lot of detail about using Membership and Authorization on controllers, pages, and using the membership provider in general. After reading this, you should have a pretty good idea of what you need to do to lock down a 'page' in  your website.

Hope this helps some.